# How to index a file into my cloud organization using a Java Http PUT request?

Tags: java, postman, put

I used Postman tool to upload a HTML file in my organization.

Using  PUT call

```
https://api.cloud.coveo.com/push/v1/organizations/*************/sources/**************************/documents?documentId=https://*******/page/page-id/SamplePage.html

Authorisation Bearer Token : ************************

headers content-type : Application/json

In body - raw code
{
"author": "John",
"date": "2020-03-18T17:56:41.666Z",
"documenttype": "HTML",
"filename": "SamplePage.html",
"language": [
"English"
],
"permanentid": "123456789",
"sourcetype": "Push",
"title": "Sample Page test",
"fileExtension": ".html",
"data": " sample.html ",
"permissions": [
{
"allowAnonymous": false,
"allowedPermissions": [
{
"identity": "AlphaTeam",
"identityType": "Group"
}
],
"deniedPermissions": [
{
"identity": "bob@example.com",
"identityType": "User"
}
]
}
]
}
```

Now how can we upload the sample file using a Java PUT request similar to Postman procedure.
Could anyone provide a solution to this.

Comment: What have you tried? What research have you done?